# Help explain the phase of the Fourier Transform of a sinusoid?

Tags: complex-analysis, fourier-analysis

Suppose you have a function $f(t) = Asin(\omega_0t)$.

Correct me if I've made an error, but the Fourier Transform of this signal on the interval $-T/2 \leq t \leq T/2$ is:

$\mathfrak{F}[f(t)]=\frac{ATi}{2}\left [ sinc((\omega-\omega_0)\frac{T}{2})-sinc((\omega+\omega_0)\frac{T}{2})\right ]$.

The phase angle is 90 degrees everywhere except at $\omega $ = 0. Why is the phase 0 at $\omega$ = 0 but 90 everywhere else? I would have expected the phase to be 90 everywhere...

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Is there a sign error? At the moment I read $0$, since both sincs cancel each other.

Comment: ah, sorry. I had missed a positive sign on the second sinc term. It is fixed now.

Comment: Ok, next question: "The phase angle is 90 degrees everywhere except at 0" Where do you read "90 degrees"?

Comment: I think because the phase angle is defined as $atan2(Imag/Real)$. Here, the real part is 0, so we have a division by zero implying the asymptote of the tangent function at $pi/2$.

Comment: Phase is not very useful for constant terms or components with energy 0.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct that the phase (of the Fourier transform!) is $\pm\pi/2$, because the Fourier transform is purely imaginary (due the time signal being an odd function of time). Note that for $\omega=0$ the phase in not zero, but it is undefined because the Fourier transform is zero for $\omega=0$.

If you have a complex number $z=re^{i\phi}$ and you set $r=0$, then $\phi$ doesn't matter anymore, it is simply undefined because in that case $z=0$ for any choice of $\phi$.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Is there no clear relationship between the phase spectrum of a Fourier Transform and the phase angle of a sinusoid? For some reason I thought they would be related...

Answer (score 0):

Your interpretation of the described signal/function is wrong. This signal has 0 phase every where. $f(t)=Asin(ω_0 t + \phi)$ is a general description of a signal with phase $\phi$, and when this phase equals 0, you get a signal with phase 0.

Comment: I have cleaned up my question a little bit. I'm confused by your response because the phase of $\mathfrak{F}[f(t)] \neq 0$.

Comment: Your solution is not a complex string, so it is not the transform result. After reading again your comment, you claim that the transform (which is complex) results frequency bins that have phase of 90? Did you try it?

Comment: $atan(\frac{Imag(\mathfrak{F}[f(t)])}{Real(\mathfrak{F}[f(t)])}) = atan(\frac{Imag(\mathfrak{F}[f(t)])}{0}) = atan(\infty) = \pi /2$.

Is this incorrect? The real component of the above transform is 0.